# keras vgg 16 shape error

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, max-pooling

im trying to fit the data with the following shape to the pretrained keras vgg19 model.

image input shape is `(32383, 96, 96, 3)`
label shape is `(32383, 17)`
and I got this error

```
expected block5_pool to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32383, 17)
```

at this line

```
model.fit(x = X_train, y= Y_train, validation_data=(X_valid, Y_valid),
              batch_size=64,verbose=2, epochs=epochs,callbacks=callbacks,shuffle=True)
```

Here's how I define my model

```
model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, input_shape=(96,96,3),classes=17)
```

How did maxpool give me a 2d tensor but not a 4D tensor ? I'm using the original model from keras.applications.vgg16. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Interesting. The issue must come from somewhere [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/vgg16.py#L136) ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from `VGG16(include_top=False,...)` as this makes your solution to load only a convolutional part of VGG. This is why `Keras` is complaining that it got 2-dimensional output insted of 4-dimensional one (4 dimensions come from the fact that convolutional output has shape `(nb_of_examples, width, height, channels)`). In order to overcome this issue you need to either set `include_top=True` or add additional layers which will squash the convolutional part - to a `2d` one (by e.g. using `Flatten`, `GlobalMaxPooling2D`, `GlobalAveragePooling2D` and a set of `Dense` layers - including a final one which should be a `Dense` with size of 17 and `softmax` activation function).